# How can I call a Google Script function on cell edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stuck figuring out how to trigger onEdit() function on cell change. It should be changing the filter criteria to hide empty rows, on edit of C2 or C4 cell. (I am hiding rows based on cell value 0/1, if 1 show rows). I already have something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const fRange = filter.getRange();
  var criteria = filter.newFilterCriteria()
  
  setHiddenValues(['0']).build();
  fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
}
```

[image: Spreadsheet screen]

It doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to solve this code?

Comment: Isn't `onEdit()` [already an event handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)? It sounds like you're not asking about triggering the function, but something inside the function. Please revise to be more clear. See [ask].

Comment: I can't find newFilterCriteria() in Filter.  How about in SpreadsheetApp instead.  And what is setHiddenValues()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

If I have understood your question clearly, your goals after triggering the `onEdit` function on column **B** (number 2) are:

- Hide rows with `0`
- Filter only rows with `1`

## ***[UPDATED]***

### Tweaked Script

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() != 3) return; //Skip script when Column B is NOT selected
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "C2" || e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4"){
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const filter = sheet.getFilter();
    const fRange = filter.getRange();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberEqualTo(1);
    filter.remove(); //Needs to remove the original filter as you can't create a filter (with new criteria) in a sheet that already has a filter
    fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  }; //Run the script only when C2 or C4 is selected
}
```

### Version 2

> using `setHiddenValues()`

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() != 3) return; //Skip script when Column B is NOT selected
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "C2" || e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4"){
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const filter = sheet.getFilter();
    const fRange = filter.getRange();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["0"]);
    filter.remove(); //Needs to remove the original filter as you can't create a filter (with new criteria) in a sheet that already has a filter
    fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  }; //Run the script only when C2 or C4 is selected
}
```

### Sample Result

> [image]

### References

- [Class FilterCriteriaBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder)
- [whenNumberEqualTo(number)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whennumberequaltonumber)
- [setHiddenValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#sethiddenvaluesvalues)

Comment: @Krzysztof B feel free correct me if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: That's exact what I was speaking about. Will test that in an hour when I will be back home. Thanks a lot for a solution. 

Comment: @Krzysztof B you're welcome. By the way, I have also updated a second version of the script using `setHiddenValues` but both scripts do the same functionality regardless. You may want to click the accept button or the up-vote on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be answered & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: Just one more thing, scripts works, but it triggers on any edited cell. It makes it annoying as it reset every time you edit any cell. Is there a way to limit it to trigger only on edit cells B2 and B4? @Irvin Jay G.

Comment: @KrzysztofB I have updated my script to skip the code when cells `C2` & `C4` are not selected (Or is it really `B2` & `B4` on your actual sheet file?).

Comment: Perfect! You are amazing. I lost over 2h fighting with that. :D It was indeed C2 & C4, just after that time I have been so angry that was making such a stupid mistakes ;)